# Matlab compiler sdk runtime

Tags: matlab, jar, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have compiled a Matlab algorithm to a java.jar file and successfully run the same algorithm in java.

to use the matlab function in java, i imported the generated jar file and also the
javabuilder.jar.

now what is :

> javabuilder.jar ?

Also it is possible to choose at compilation settings between

> Runtime downloaded from web

and

> Runtime included in package

I set Runtime downloaded from web and included only the two jar files to my project and could run the algorithm.

Where is the Matlab runtime necessary? and can i just use my Jar files also on a linux computer?

Answer (score 1):

The javabuilder. jar contains the wrapper functions to communicate with the matlab runtime.
The matlab runtime is written in c++ and has to be installed on the system where the javabuilder + matlab function jar is used.

The runtime installer is included in the package file that is created by matlab to download the runtime from web or can be included with the package.